# How to Store json data file in a services using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Just want to know your idea wht will be my approach on how to store external json data file into a services so that i can inject it into different controllers

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [ngTranslation](https://github.com/a8m/ng-translation) module.
with this service you can store the static content(some json file, etc..) outside of the code, and not dirty your controllers/services...

**EXAMPLE:**
JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['ng-translation'])
  .config(['ngTranslationProvider', function(ngTranslationProvider) {
    ngStaticProvider
      .setDirectory('/assets/static')
      .setFilesSuffix('.json')
      .langsFiles({
        demo1: 'demo1',
        demo2: 'demo2'
      })
  }]);

//inject to controller
function PanelController($scope, translateFilter) {
  $scope.panelContent = translateFilter('key','fileName')
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- use as a filter {{ key | translate: fileName  }}-->
<p>{{ key | translate: fileName }}</p>

<!-- use ng-translate directive, similar to ng-bind-->
<p ng-translate="file(key)"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends on the architecture of your application but I guess you could create a factory or service that will store data then simply inject that factory wherever needed.

If the data needs to be persistent, I would use something like localStorage. If it's a really small amount of data and your app cannot support HTML5, I would use cookies.

The more you elaborate the more accurate answer you will get.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at the angularjs tutorial. It specifically address this issue.
First go though http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 where you include the json in controller.
Then follow http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11 where it is moved to service.

$http.get() can be used to retrive data from REST urls as well.